# How does logging into the console works in the Java Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a very simple Spring application, but I can't not get a `System.out.println` statement to print into the console.

This is the main app file where I am printing an env variable set in a `.yml` file

```
import path.config.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(MainApplication.class);
        app.run();
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("env: " + config.getEnv());
    }

}
```

The configuration file looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Config {
    private String env;

    public void setEnv(String env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    public String getEnv() {
        return this.env;
    }
}
```

Finally the properties yml file

```
spring: 
    profiles.active: dev
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
---
spring:
    profiles: dev
env: dev
---
spring:
    profiles: test
env: test
---
spring:
    profiles: prod
env: prod
```

The Spring app builds a runs fine, however, I can't see the `env` variable to show in the terminal. I have seen examples of people using Controllers with a Request endpoint just to debug the environment variables in the browser. Is that the only option?

Comment: are you not getting any logs in console ? does your app starts ?

Comment: the app starts. I see all the Spring initialization processes in the console (tomcat, h2, etc...), but not sure how to find standard logs with `Systemm.out.println`

Comment: check my answer @chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of changes to your code, you don't need to use `new` keyword for starting spring application, you can directly use static [run](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html) method

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class);
  
}
```

Second thing the `run` method in `MainApplication` will only execute if that class implements [CommandLineRunner](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner.html)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MainApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private Config config;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class);
    }

    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
          System.out.println("env: " + config.getEnv());
     }

  }
```